# NodeJS, MongoDB: Database read/write strategy for performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

This is my first attempt at a web application with a DB access so I'm not sure what is the accepted way of doing a DB write/read.

In basic terms, my application will have one user updating a field in the DB (a number) and many other users will read it (through a REST api). The updating of the number will not be frequent (maybe once per minute) but the reads can be more than that, about 100/minute. I understand this is a very low rate of DB write/reads that it wouldn't really matter I do direct read from the DB, but I want to know what are the strategies typically used in web applications.

For example, is it better to maintain this number as a variable in memory and serve for reads, so that I don't need to access the DB each time, and then only write to DB (and re-fetch the value to memory) when there is an update to this field. Or is it better to read from the DB for each read entry.

I apologize if the question is vague. I put NodeJS and MonogDB as tags because that's what I'm using in the app.

Thank you.

Comment: Question: why do you need a DB at all?  That said, I think caching in memory for reads makes sense.

Comment: Well I'm actually storing more information than the number. I just mentioned only that to simplify the case. And I will have more than one number being updated by users. So I want a solution that can scale.

Comment: That's what I figured, but how many numbers?  An array of 1000 numbers (or hashs) "scales" real easy.  Just trying to get more info and context.  I have a vaguely similar project (data changes rarely, gets read often) and only went with the DB when queries were needed.

Comment: Thank you. I'm also starting feel an array would be the way to go. I will be storing more fields so I definitely need a DB, but for this number I probably can use in memory and write to DB only when the user logs out.

Comment: The "when to write" is a good question.  I save every two hours but seems like there must be a better way.  :-)

Comment: use redis... it will periodically persist the data from memory to disk automatically... and that parameter is configurable.

Comment: THank you Mukesh. I have done the implementation in Mongo and although I have read good things about Redis in terms of performance, I kept away from it because it seems complex for me to handle (this is my first dev with a DB)